# He worries more [than is necessary]. Is 'than is necessary' a relative clause?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, relative-clauses

> He worries **more** [than is necessary].

Might I trouble you to tell me whether or not 'than is necessary' is a relative clause modifying 'more'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The *than* clause is a complement of *more* - it completes its meaning.

I suppose that semantically its function is similar to a non-restrictive relative clause; but

1) Than is not a relative pronoun (or a relative anything else)

2) The head of a relative clause is almost always a noun (or noun phrase), not an adjective or adverb.